# Notice: Use of undefined constant - assumed ' '

Tags: wp-debug, constants

I turned on debug mode and see the following in my header:

**Notice: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' '**

I'm using the following function in header.php:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    echo $current_user->display_name; //affected line
} else {
...
}?>
```

Comment: I don't get that error, and I don't know why that particular code would cause it.

Comment: sounds like your currently logged in user doesn't have a display name set; did you check what it's set to under the admin dashboard -> users or in the database?

Comment: The fields are properly filled and saved in admin, the error shows up even if user_email, user_login, user_firstname etc... is echoed.
BTW, it works fine, I'm just curious why the debug throws this error.

Comment: Since the constant is empty `''` I wonder if you have an unprintable character on the line.